# Xserver sets monitor to sleep after 10 minutes

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, firefox, screen-energy-saving

My installation,
Ubuntu server 14.04 with just xorg and firefox installed.
The server boots up and immediatly starts firefox with the disired webpage in fullscreen mode.
After 10 minutes my monitor goes to sleep.
How can i disable the sleep function of the monitor?

Answer (score 2):

My Debian system is using **KDE** 5.26.

---

And my X didn't have the DPMS (display power management signaling) feature:

```bash
$ xset
    To control Energy Star (DPMS) features:
        -dpms      Energy Star features off
```

```bash
$ xset q
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Server does not have the DPMS Extension
```

```bash
$ xset -dpms
server does not have extension for -dpms option
```

---

Instead, it was being managed by KDE, according to the `~/.config/powermanagementprofilesrc` configuration. This file is what KDE's `System settings` GUI configures. The `[AC][DPMSControl]` is what you're looking for if you're using KDE. Comment it or remove it to disable the DPMS feature.

```
[AC]
icon=battery-charging

[AC][DPMSControl]
idleTime=540
lockBeforeTurnOff=0

[AC][DimDisplay]
idleTime=60000

[AC][HandleButtonEvents]
lidAction=1
powerButtonAction=16
powerDownAction=16
```

[image: System settings]

It can also be configured with `kwriteconfig5` on a terminal: `kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/powermanagementprofilesrc --group AC --group DPMSControl --key idleTime 540`.

---

### `Screen locking`

If you're also interested in configuring `System settings`' `Screen locking`, refer to https://superuser.com/a/1768085/644826.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `xset -dpms` should do it, though your desktop environment may have extra facilities for setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xset s off`. This command disables the monitors timeout feature.

Answer (score 0):

When the server starts, he also starts a init.d file to start this certain website.
The file looks like this :
"startx -e firefox "http://www.mywebsite.com"

Looking at the answers i added an extra line "xset -dpms; xset s blank"
this didn't solve my problem.

I also closed the window and typed "xset -dpms; xset s blank" in terminal when x was started, this also didn't solve my problem.

Am i doing something wrong?